# Tweak output of a script that extracts data from CSV

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a file with names of directors and their work like names of the movies produced by them and all the info relating to this.

I have given the first two lines of the file here.

I want a solution like the name of the director and the number of the movies made by him in front of his/her name.I'm able to get the number of movies as follows by using sort and unique commands in pipelines. The code looks like

```
tail -n+2 biopic.csv | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c
```

which provides me a list of directors preceded by the number of movies they made.

What I actually want is the name of the directors followed ',' and then number of movies they made.

Is there any way I can insert a comma in the output of this command?

```
title   site    country year_rele   box_offic   director    number_ subject type_of_s   race_kno    subject_r   person_of   subject_s   lead_actor_actress               
10 Rillingt http://ww   UK  1971    -   Richard Fl  1   John Chris  Criminal    Unknown     0   Male    Richard Attenborough
```

Comment: mm, if that awk works I suppose your input looks more like `"title","site","country"...` than what was shown here, yes?

Comment: Yup, that awk does work and gives me the output like

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe it to `perl -nle 'print "$2, $1" if /(\d+)\s(.+)/'`

This simply run a line-by-line expression from standard input.

Comment: Thanks for your input...I tried this but not able to understand it completely!

Comment: Did the command work though? I based the regex on your description of the output data.

Comment: I tried this command but for me, it didn't work...tried all the combinations of spacing and all...Then I just gave up as I was able to get the result with the awk command...and also I haven't tried to have deeper understanding of perl command as I'm just trying to learn more of awk...which is very easy to understand. You may differ in your opinion as an experienced person though.

Comment: That's a shame -- glad you found a simpler command though.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, i made a test biopic.csv and with some lines based on your example, separated by commas.

```
10,Rillingt,http://ww,UK 1971,-,Richard Fl,1,John Chris,Criminal,Unknown,0,Male,Richard Attenborough
10,Rillingt,http://ww,UK 1971,-,Don Fl,1,John Chris,Criminal,Unknown,0,Male,Richard Attenborough
...
```

Running your command gives me

```
$ tail -n+2 biopic.csv | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c
6 Don Fl
5 Richard Fl
```

To reverse it, and add a comma, you can use awk again.
Split on space what you already have, and add characters you need back in (using "").
Like

```
print $2 " " $3  ", " $1
```

as in

```
<firstname> <lastname>, <count>
```

It gives me this

```
$ tail -n+2 biopic.csv | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | awk -F ' ' '{print $2 " " $3  ", " $1}'
Don Fl, 6
Richard Fl, 5
```

Comment: Hey, I just tried to modify bit of your suggested commands, and guess what I worked. Thanks a lot!